Animation in react js
I have a circular animated loader. Now i want to add normal keyframes like we do in normal css.The problem is the data is 25% than only 25% of circle should have blue color and other 75% have any other color, right?. I want to apply animate-spin. I don't want it to be static.
Animate-spin on load from o to the desired value rather than to keep it tsatic that looks boring
